# Do rounding errors occur also in floats representing integers?

Tags: java, rounding, rounding-error

When creating a range of numbers as follows,

```
    float increment = 0.01f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        float value = i * increment;
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

it is clear, that I will end up for some i with values like 
0.049999997, which are no exact multiples of 0.01, due to rounding errors.

When I try the same with floats in the range of usual integers, I have never seen the same problem:

```
float increment = 1.0f; //Still a float but representing an int value
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    float value = i * increment;
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

One could expect, that this also prints out e.g. 49.999999 instead of 50, which I never saw however.

I am wondering, whether I can rely on that for any value of i and any value of increment, as long as it represents an integer (although its type is float).

And if so, I would be interested in an explanation, why rounding errors can not happen in that case.

Comment: Maybe not an answer, but a good resource - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Don't ever, _ever_, _Ever_ use `float` for calculations.  Use `double`.  The only reason you should ever use `float` is to save space when you need to store an array of them.  With computers having multiple gigabytes of core these days, I would not use `float` on anything less than 100-million of them in memory or trillions of them on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because float is based on floating point notation.

In rude words it tries to represent your decimal number as a sum of fractions of power 2.

It means it will try to sum 1/2^n1 + 1/2^n2 + 1/2^n3 .... 1/2^nm until gets closes or exact value that you put.

For example (rude):
0.5 it will represent as 1/2
0.25 it will represent as 1/2²
0.1 it will represent as 1/2^4
but in this case it will mutiply the number by 1.600000023841858 (mantissa) and it will give a number closer but not equal to 1  (1/2^4 x 1.600000023841858 = 0,100000001

Now you can see why after some loops the value changes to nonsense values

For rich detail of how it works read floating points [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

If you want precision you should use for example a BigDecimal from Java that uses another architecture to represent decimal numbers.

Double has the same problem.

Check this tool to see the repressentation of floating point:
http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: It's not exactly the answer. But thanks for the link to the tool, which helped me to understand.
By entering numbers of the type 2^n+1 for n = 1,2,3 and so on, one can see that the mantissa bits are able to represent the factor f = 1/2^n up to n = 24. This factor is used to calculate the final number as 2^n * (1 + f). So the first rounding problem for integers occurs with 2^24 + 1 which can not be represented exactly, as starting with 2^24 the last mantissa bit has already a "value" of 2. For 2^25 its value is 4 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Integers in a certain range (about up to one million or so) can be represented exactly as a float. Therefore you don't get rounding errors when you work only with them.

Comment: What you say is true if "work with them" only means add or subtract or multiply.  Once you do a division that gives a non-integer result (e.g., 1.0/7.0) or call a trig function, then your results will no longer be exact.

Comment: @jameslarge Exactly, what I meant was that the operands *and* the result must be integers.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really represent an integer. It's still a float that you're just attempting to add the value 1.0 to. You'll get rounding errors as soon as 1.0 underflows (whenever the exponent gets larger than zero).